# My arduino SD code cannot find files or create new ones

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-c++

So i have this code that should open a file and write to it, sadly it cannot be found/opened. and i cannot open a new one.

The Cardinfo.io example runs with no problems, and it can detect the card just fine.

The code is:

`

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <SD.h>
Sd2Card card;
SdVolume volume;
SdFile root;

const int chipSelect = 4;
String IPRange = "192.168.1.";
String port = "21";

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(115200);
  SD.begin();
  Serial.print("Initializing SD card...");

  if (!card.init(SPI_HALF_SPEED, chipSelect)) {
    Serial.println("initialization failed. Things to check:");
    Serial.println("* is a card inserted?");
    Serial.println("* is your wiring correct?");
    Serial.println("* did you change the chipSelect pin to match your shield or module?");
    while (1);
  } else {
    Serial.println("Wiring is correct and a card is present.");
  }

  ListIP(); 
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}

void ListIP() {
   if (SD.exists("ip.txt")) {
    Serial.println("IT DOES EXIST");
 }
 else{
  Serial.println("IT IS GONE?!");
 }
  File dataFile  = SD.open("ip.txt",FILE_WRITE);
  delay(100);
  if (dataFile ) {
    dataFile.println("FTP Server: ");
    dataFile.print(IPRange);
    dataFile.print(" ");
    dataFile.print(port);
    dataFile.close();
  }
  else {
    Serial.println("error opening ip.txt");
  }
}
```

`

with the error message being:
[image]

Comment: the CardInfo 'example' is a diagnostics tool, not an example. it works on a lower level.. see the other examples. (you need SD.begin)

Comment: @Juraj yeah sorry i left it out by accident here, sadly that does not fix it. I have the same error (and yes i have checked formatting (FAT32) and that the card works on pc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, i forgot `SD.begin(4)`

Comment: no. you used card.init instead of SD.begin